# Can Android RecyclerView contain Non Container Views instead of View Container

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, recyclerlistview

So basically `RecyclerView` inflates item `View` wrapped in (Layout Holder). E.g.
For a `RecyclerView` the items that are inflated in the adapter are like :

`list_item.xml` contains below code:

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent">
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/option"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:text="TESTING"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Can it not be like below code?

```
<merge xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/option"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:text="TESTING"/>
</merge>
```

Because `RecyclerView` is Container View that can hold simple non-container views and container views (like `LinearLayout` etc.)
Container Views - `View` which can hold simple views (`TextView`, button etc.) as well as container Views (like `LinearLayout` etc.).
Simple Views - can not hold any other view within it.

And during inflation in the adapter, we attach it root:-

```
final View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                    .inflate(R.layout.dialog_locker_open_item, parent, true);
```

The above give exception.

It should have merged but was getting expectation during inflation.

Answer (score 1):

Each `ViewHolder` needs to contain one root view (constructor argument of `ViewHolder`) so `RecyclerView` can detach and recycle it when needed.

It's not designed to keep track of "multiple non-container views" per item (which would happen if you were inflating with `<merge>` tag).

Also `inflate` with `attachToParent=true` is conceptually wrong and will always fail as `RecyclerView.Adapter` is not the component responsible for laying out the views in `RecyclerView` (this is the duty of `RecyclerView.LayoutManager`).